# How to ascertain the gender of the subject in a sentence in Hebrew?

Tags: hebrew

In Hebrew, we, of course, read from right to left. Take the following sentence, for example:

> המורה למוזיקה אומרת לדני לא להתרגעש לפני הקונצרט
> *ha-moreh/morah le-muzikah omeret le-Dani lo lehitragesh lifnei ha-kontsert*
> The music teacher said to Dani not to get anxious before the concert

The subject here is המורה, which can mean either a male teacher (pronounced *ha-moreh*) or a female teacher (pronounced *ha-morah*).

The form of the verb tells us that מורה here refers to a female teacher and should thus be pronounced *ha-morah*, but the verb comes **after** the subject. Before getting to the verb, it’s a 50-50 guess whether the subject is male or female.

Is there a way to ascertain the gender of the subject without having to read ahead when reading the sentence linearly? And if not, does this ambiguity not cause confusion in practical terms?

Comment: If you say that sentence in English, the teacher's gender is never indicated at all, is it? That doesn't seem to cause any problems for English-speakers.

Comment: Indeed, but in Hebrew, the pronunciation changes depending on the gender - same spelling. If male, 'haMoreh', if female, 'haMorah'.

Comment: "By the verb conjugation, we know that מורה refers to a female teacher. ... Is there another way to ascertain the gender of the subject?" Why would you want to ignore the part of the grammar that answers your question?

Comment: @curiousdannii because when you read the sentence out loud, you have to pronounce the subject before the verb. The question is if it does not pose problems that you have to scan ahead. This aspect should be made clearer, but it’s a legitimate linguistic question.

Comment: @Keelan That's certainly *a* question, but how do you know that's what the OP meant?

Comment: That is what I meant, thank you to both. I should perhaps edit my original post.

Comment: @curiousdannii from his comment. Alvaro Neto: yes, thank you!

Comment: @AlvaroNeto I’ve edited the question to better incorporate these details into the text, but you should add a transcription and translation of the sentence as well. Even if you need to know Hebrew to be able to _answer_ the question, you shouldn’t need to know Hebrew to be able to _read_ it.

Comment: In practice you tend to have context for whatever you're reading, so I expect cases of confusion are pretty rare. It's not that big a deal to have to repeat a word in a different gender once in a long while.

Comment: @Cairnarvon honestly, you should post that as an answer; it deserves to be accepted.

Comment: From introspection as a native speaker, I'd say that sometimes context makes the gender clear, sometimes you realize there's an ambiguity and scan ahead to resolve it, and sometimes you do guess wrong and have to correct yourself.

Comment: @TKR This too could be posted as an answer!

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet that's a much better formulation of the question, thank you!

Comment: @TKR I agree that this clarifies my question quite well. Thank you. As I am learning Hebrew on my own, I still find myself often guessing wrong. I can imagine that the problem is more with the learning process, rather than the application of the language.

Comment: @Cairnarvon thank you for the clarification.

Comment: Either you are speaking, in which case you know, or you are reading, in which case you read ahead, or you make a mistake, in which case you correct it afterwards.

Comment: Any time  you hear a sentence, you don't have all the information until the end (if that). What makes this situation different?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not really different from המורה בבית *hamore/a bavayit* "The teacher is in the house", except that a later word may show that the reader made the wrong choice.

It's therefore not really different from English *They read the newspaper*, which could have two different pronunciations of *read* with two different meanings - "present" (actually, timeless or habitual) and past. A later word that somehow specifies time may indicate which was meant, eg *they read the newspaper every day* vs *they read the newspaper yesterday*.

Comment: Indeed, even with the adverbial _every day_ the sentence remains ambiguous; e.g., “My aunt and uncle were of the old world: they lived in a grand house, they always ate their dinner at 8 o’clock on the dot, and they read the newspaper every day over breakfast”.

Answer (score 0):

If this were going to be a problem, let's say it's being read aloud from a teleprompter, then the writer would put in the vowels for that particular word.

Comment: Do you have examples where pointing is used to disambiguate? This seems to contradict https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Niqqud.

Comment: @Keelan The niqqud article doesn’t seem to mention it, but the [notes in the _ktiv hasar niqqud_ article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ktiv_hasar_niqqud#Notes) do seem to give an example that would apply here.

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that **it would either be evident from context, or irrelevant**. If it were relevant and not evident from context, then you could write it with the vowel diacritics.

This is probably at least part of the reason that languages like this take one gender as the default, instead of always indicating. I'm not *too* familiar with Hebrew, but I'm pretty sure that the male form of a human noun is the default, so *ha-moreh* would at least work with a female teacher. And when they read further and see the feminine verb, they could correct themselves.

Comment: I only know ancient Hebrew, but I doubt that the masculine would be grammatical with a feminine verb. (There is a relatively rare phenomenon that a feminine subject takes a masculine verb, but it’s the opposite and I don’t know if this happens in Modern Hebrew too.) Also, according to https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Niqqud vowel pointing is not used for disambiguation.

Answer (score -2):

In Hebrew the verb usually precedes its subject.  This means that one should already know from the verb what the subject's gender is when reading it.

For example:

> בְּרֵאשִׁ֖ית בָּרָ֣א אֱלֹהִ֑ים אֵ֥ת הַשָּׁמַ֖יִם וְאֵ֥ת הָאָֽרֶץ׃
> (Bereshit 1:1) In the beginning God created the heaven and the earth.
> (Genesis 1:1)

Reading carefully from right to left in that Hebrew text, we see the word order: "bereshit" (in beginning) "bara" (created, third-person masculine singular) "elohim" (God) "et" ([direct-object marker (DOM), not translated]) "ha-shamayim" (the heavens) "wa-et" (and [DOM]) "ha-arets" (the earth).

So, "In the beginning created God...."  This subject-after-verb format is the usual grammar, though many exceptions exist.

In most languages, a reader needs to read ahead somewhat, if for no other reason than to know where to place proper expression in the sentence.  For example, is it going to end as a question or as a statement?

Reading takes practice in any language, and Hebrew is no exception.  In fact, with Hebrew it is common to need to read at least a short distance ahead.  If one has the word "כָל/kal" in Hebrew followed by the mappiq (like a hyphen), it must be read as "kol", yet the spelling does not change: the punctuation after the syllable determined its pronunciation, e.g. "כָל־הָאָ֔רֶץ" (kol-ha-arets/all the earth).  Granted this is but a short distance beyond the start of the word, but it illustrates the need to look ahead before one begins to pronounce the text.

Comment: This question is about Modern Hebrew, which usually has Subject-Verb-Object order.

Comment: @Keelan Perhaps I should ask the next question here, then: "How does one know which version of Hebrew one is asking about before answering the question?"  I note that you are the only one who has used the word "Modern" on this entire page up until now, and you are not the one who asked the question.  In either case, readers must look ahead--sometimes that is simply the truth, whether one wishes for it to be so or not.

Comment: The quote in the question uses SVO; it talks about music (a Greek loan that postdates Biblical Hebrew) and music teachers, concerts (a loan from French) and people called Dani; and its transliteration is clearly modern, not Biblical. Those are all pretty clear clues that this is not about Biblical Hebrew, despite the word ‘Modern’ not being explicitly used.

Comment: Furthermore, in the English question example "is it going to end ...?" the reader knows by word order that the sentence is an interrogative well before rising intonation has to be initiated. The word כָּל is always pronounced *kol*, and this could also be derived from the lack of cantillation mark on the kaf if needed; the reader does not need to scan ahead.

Comment: @Keelan You'll have to take that _kol_ pronunciation up with the Jewish rabbis, who will tell you that when the word is not connected to another word with a maqqef it is pronounced as it is spelled, with the _qamats_ sounding as it usually should.  While this is an exceptional case that it should be pronounced as _kol_ at all, it is common for this word, as it does usually occur with the maqqef.  Just the same, if it stands alone, it is _kal_.

Comment: Can you give an example of freestanding *kal*? In Gen 2:5, for instance, you will see that the word is not followed by maqqef, and it’s pointed with holem, not qametz.

Comment: @Keelan I did a search and could not find an example.  Now I'm wondering why the rabbi made such a point of explaining this pronunciation in his class about ten days ago.  I thought I remembered seeing a text in 1 Samuel that had the free-standing _kal_, but my memory is no longer clear as to which passage we were reading that day.  Now I want to ask the rabbi again about this.

Comment: In fact, there turns out to be one case: Ps 119:96. I did not expect that. However, the pointing still indicates that it is pronounced *kol*. You are correct that there are two pronunciations of qametz in some traditions. It is pronounced *o* in closed unstressed syllables and *ā* everywhere else. When a word is joined with maqqef to the following word, it forms one prosodic unit and only one stress; for this reason כל will in these environments always be pronounced *kol*. But since the word is otherwise written with holem, I don't use it myself as an example of short qametz.

Comment: The example I use myself is חָכְמָה *ḥokhmā* 'wisdom' vs. חָֽכְמָה *ḥākhəmā* 'she was wise'. In both words the second qametz is stressed (and in an open syllable), so pronounced long. In the first word the first qametz is unstressed and in a closed syllable, so pronounced *o*. In the second word the first qametz is unstressed, but the meteg forces a long pronunciation *ā*, which also triggers the vocal schwa. If you use the cantillation marks to determine where the stress lies and follow these rules, you do not need to look at the maqqef for pronunciation.

Comment: @Keelan I didn't wait to ask the rabbi, but asked another instructor in class today: The "kal" form is _construct state_, with the "kol" form (having the holem) being the normal spelling.  Because it is in construct state, it is typically (necessarily) connected to the next word, hence the high frequency of maqqef associated with it.  The discussion unfortunately took another turn before I had opportunity to ask about the "kal" pronunciation more specifically.

Comment: The example in Gen 2:5 is in constrict state, too. It’s correct that all cases with qametz are in construct state, but construct state can also be written with holem.